# updating nulls value in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

how do i set a column value to null if the user don't select value or set the new value when the user select value

```
create procedure update2
 @SSN int,
 @Employee_FirstName varchar(50),
 @Employee_lastName varchar(50),
 @gender_ID int,
 @Department_ID int,
 @location_ID int,
 @salary decimal(18, 3)

as

Update Employee set Employee_FirstName= @Employee_FirstName,
Employee_lastName=@Employee_lastName,gender=@gender_ID,Department_ID = @Department_ID,
location_ID=@location_ID or location_ID is null  , salary=@salary
where SSN = @SSN
```

Comment: Can you rephrase the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare @location_ID as null

```
CREATE PROCEDURE update2
@SSN INT ,
@Employee_FirstName VARCHAR(50) ,
@Employee_lastName VARCHAR(50) ,
@gender_ID INT ,
@Department_ID INT ,
@location_ID INT = NULL ,
@salary DECIMAL(18, 3)

AS 

UPDATE  Employee
SET     Employee_FirstName = @Employee_FirstName ,
        Employee_lastName = @Employee_lastName ,
        gender = @gender_ID ,
        Department_ID = @Department_ID ,
        location_ID = @location_ID ,
        salary = @salary
WHERE   SSN = @SSN
```

Comment: i have do these answer but still have problim this the error msg 

The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Emp_DB_Location". The conflict occurred in database "test", table "dbo.Location", column 'ID'. The statement has been terminated

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, If I correctly understood your question -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.update2 

    @SSN INT,
    @Employee_FirstName VARCHAR(50),
    @Employee_lastName VARCHAR(50),
    @gender_ID INT,
    @Department_ID INT,
    @location_ID INT,
    @salary DECIMAL(18, 3)

AS BEGIN

    UPDATE dbo.Employee
    SET 
          Employee_FirstName = @Employee_FirstName
        , Employee_lastName = @Employee_lastName
        , gender = @gender_ID
        , Department_ID = @Department_ID
        , location_ID = ISNULL(location_ID, @location_ID) --<-- ?? 
        , salary = @salary
    WHERE SSN = @SSN

END
```

Answer (score 0):

@location_ID INT = NULL -- specify NULL like this wherever you need

But you have to remove any relations(foreign key) with this particular column otherwise you will get conflict occur error at the time of updation

Thanks
Arun Antony